# Replace '1' with 'Q' and 'Q' with '1'. Char replacement in string. Java

Tags: java, string

Hi I need some help with my internship test task. I've read it a couple of times and I can't even say that I'm surely know what I need to do. So the task is:

***You must generate a string of random length consisting of random ASCII characters. After that you need to replace all entries of '1' with 'Q' and 'Q' with '1' in it. To complete the task you are allowed to change one substring with another as many times as you want. For example as a result of changing "ww" -> "wert" the string "wwwwwQ" will become "wertwertwQ". Write a program which does required changes in the most optimal way (doing minimum amount of replacements).***

I've already implemented string generation and i simply don't know what to do next. As said in the header, i need to do this using Java. Could you please offer me some way to solve this task?

As i said what i've already done is **genString()** which generates a char array for me and a **replace()** method which does what intended but it not uses substrings so it seems that this task should be done another way.

```
public static char[] genString()
    {
        int n = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;

        char[] arr = new char[n];

        for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = (char)(rand.nextInt(95) + 33);
        }



        return arr;

    }

    public static void replace(char[] arr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = (arr[i] == 'Q') ? '1'
                    : (arr[i] == '1' ) ? 'Q'
                    : arr[i];
        }
    }
```

What i actually don't understand is that how the substrings could be used there. I don't understand how going from **"wwwwwQ" to "wertwertwQ"** -like replacements will help me replace the 'Q' in it

Comment: Post your code and point out your exact problem please. So far, the task seems pretty clear.

Comment: Could you please offer me some way to solve this task?

Comment: No, you won't get the answer here without showing some incentive to solve it on your own. If you have a problem, that's ok to ask. It's not okay to just ask for the solution. 

So 1) post what you have done so far 2) Describe, which subtask exactly is unclear.

Comment: `String s = "..."; s = s.replace("...", "...").replace("...", "...");` But the interesting problem is of course to "simultaneously" swap '1' and 'Q'.

Comment: I don't like the idea to replace thrice. You would need a temporary replacement, that is not part of the string from the beginning. Just iterate through the string and swap char `Q` and `1`.

Comment: "Just iterate through the string and swap char Q and 1" - it's good when there's equal amount of them in string. And, as i said, the string generates randomly so there's not a big chances to have them in equal amount.

Comment: @MetalMike No, I meant you iterate through the string and if you find a 'Q', replace it with a '1' and if you find a `1` replace it with a `Q`.

Comment: @tgmath As you can see in my replace() method that's exactly what i've done. But it not seems the right solution because it not uses substrings.

Comment: @MetalMike I suspect the hint want to help you if you consider to use a buildin replace, that replaces all occurences of a string with another string. An example to swap would be(using '.ONE.' as temp.) :  'ew1Q121Q' => 'ew.ONE.Q.ONE.2.ONE.Q' => 'ew.ONE.1.ONE.2.ONE.1' => 'ewQ1Q2Q1'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the fewest replacements, I would use a stream-based approach:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i) == 'Q') {
        sb.setCharAt(i, '1');
    } else if (str.charAt(i) == '1') {
        sb.setCharAt(i, 'Q');
    } 
}
return sb.toString();
```

Using a `StringBuilder` make manipulating the string a lot more efficient, because a new string doesn't have to be created every time you change a letter.

Answer (score -1):

well, try this code:

```
public String Replace(String theString, String first, String Second)
    {
        String result =""; 

        result=theString.replace(first, Second); 
        return result;
    }
```

Example of using:

```
System.out.println(Replace("wwwwwQ", "ww", "wert"));// result will be: wertwertwQ
```

I hope it will help you, best regards

Comment: That only wraps a call to `String#replace` and once you have replaced all the Qs by 1s how do you plan to replace the original 1s by Qs?